# .htaccess - whitelist allowed URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a simple PHP webapp, and would like to limit the URLs that users can access to a couple PHP files and a directory or two. Any URL that is not whitelisted in the .htaccess should be denied.

Example whitelist:

```
/
/assets/*
index.php
profile.php
favicon.ico
```

How is this most easily possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `RewriteRule` in your root .htaccess will work:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^(index\.php|profile\.php|favicon\.ico|assets/.*)?$ - [F,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do something similar. Specific files, then folders.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|style\.css|sitemap\.xml)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/img/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
```